# bootstrap styling not working on setting content security header

Tags: html, css, angular, content-security-policy

[screen short of page with console error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIuHp.png

I am trying to add Content-Security-Header in my angular project

### component.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';style-src 'self'">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shop</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### component.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}
.brand-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

---

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';style-src 'self'">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shop</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

on adding the header my style applied is broken.

> adding 'unsafe-inline' will fix but is there a more secure or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's [impossible](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631) to avoid `'unsafe-inline'` in `style-src` directive. Pls see para 1 at the "Suggested Steps":

> 1. We should clearly state that allowing 'unsafe-inline' in style-src is required for Angular applications.

Comment: thanks for your answer and for supporting document